# How To minimize the height of pdf-viewer-reactjs

Tags: css, reactjs, styling, pdf-viewer, pdfview

I am New to react, I am using pdf-viewer-reactjs to display the pdf file, I want to fix the height of the pdf, I tried with style, it is not working, even I wrapped the pdf with div and fix the height it is also not working, I tried even height props it is also not working, anyone please guide me with this thank u in advance.

`import PDFViewer from 'pdf-viewer-reactjs'`

`<PDFViewer document={{url: url}} hideNavbar={true}  scale={true} css={classes.pdfView}/>`

Answer (score 1):

By using CanvasCss we can minimize the height and width

```
<PDFViewer 
      document={{url:url}}
      hideNavbar={true}
      scale={0.2}
      canvasCss={classes.pdfView}
    />
```

style.js

```
pdfView:{
    height:"200px",
    overflow:"auto",
  }
```

Comment: This is actually supported by the README for pdf-viewer-reactjs https://github.com/ansu5555/pdf-viewer-reactjs

Answer (score 0):

Having a parent element with a fixed height and an overflow of hidden may solve the problem for you.

```
<div style={{ height: "500px", overflow: "hidden" }}>
    <PDFViewer 
        document={{url: url}} 
        hideNavbar={true}  
        scale={true} 
        css={classes.pdfView}
    />
</div>
```